# Two versions of same email to two different recipients using class.phpmailer.php

Tags: php, email, loops, phpmailer

I'm trying to send two versions of the same email to two recipients using phpMailer

Depending on the email I need to send one version or another.

At the moment I'm able to send only the same version to both email address

```
<?php               
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$maileremail = $_POST['maileremail'];
$subject = $_POST['subject']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$text = 'The person that contacted you is  '.$fname.'  E-mail: '.$maileremail.' Subject: '.$subject.' Message: '.$message.' :';
$body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$text);

$text2 = 'The person that contacted you is  '.$fname.'  E-mail: REMOVED - To get email address you must login Subject: '.$subject.' Message: '.$message.' :';
$body2 = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$text2);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "xxxxx.xxxxx.xxx"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;                  // SMTP connection will not close after each email sent
$mail->Host = "xxxxx.xxxxx.xxx"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port = XXXXXXXX;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username = "xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password = "XXXXXXXX";        // SMTP account password
$mail->SetFrom('xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx', 'XXXXXXXX');
$mail->Subject = $subject;

$add = array("first@email.xxx", "second@email.xxx");

foreach($add as $address) { 
    if($address == "first@email.xxx") {
        $mail->AddAddress($address, "xxxxxxxxx"); 
        $mail->Body = $body;
    }
    elseif($address == "second@email.xxx") {
        $mail->AddAddress($address, "xxxxxxxxx"); 
        $mail->Body = $body2;
    }                       
}

if(!$mail->Send()) {
     echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
     echo "<h3><b>Message sent!</b></h3>";
}}?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to do all the setup once for minimal repetition, simply clone your `$mail` object in your `foreach($add)` loop:

```
foreach ( $add as $address ) {
    $current = clone $mail;

    if ( $address == 'first@mail.com' ) {

        $current->AddAddress($address, "xxxxxxxxx");
        $current->Body = $body;
        $current->send();

   } elseif....
```

This creates a separate clone of your `$mail` object for every loop, allowing you to add different email bodies, subjects, etc. without having to rewrite all connection settings.

Comment: Brian Nort: It works fine but I get the following error "Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address." But as I said it works as it should.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to seach the `$maileremail` inside `$add` and send the desired email.

```
$add = array("first@email.xxx", "second@email.xxx");
$mail->AddAddress($maileremail, "xxxxxxxxx");

if($maileremail === $add[0])
$mail->Body = $body;
if($maileremail === $add[1])
$mail->Body = $body2;


if(!$mail->Send()) {
     echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
     echo "<h3><b>Message sent!</b></h3>";
}
```

---

**EDITED:**
I misunderstood the question. [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1727159/brian-north) is right.

Comment: can you give an example of the if/else-if condition ? Using $mail->ClearAllRecipients(); only send an email to one recipient. Thanks

Comment: I assume you have a list of recipients and you want different email body for different recipient and not that you wish to send email to everyone?

Comment: Yes, that is why I have $body and $body2, depending on the email address I want to send one "body" or the other

Comment: I'm sorry but $maileremail = $_POST['maileremail']; SO $maileremail != $add[0] AND $maileremail != $add[1]

Comment: You have a list of email addresses in $add and you need to compare the $maileremail to one of these addresses and set the mail body based on that, Right? That's what the code is doing.